# Can the Phong shading model be implemented in fixed function pipeline OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, 3d, phong

The [Phong shading technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) interpolates normals at vertices to achieve a smooth shading effect. It is usually combined with the [Phong illumination model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model), and it can be implemented in modern OpenGL. However, does fixed-function pipeline OpenGL (*legacy* OpenGL)
include support for it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**No, it can't.** Modern OpenGL enables programmers to customise the rendering pipeline in many ways, which enables them to implement this technique. However, *legacy* OpenGL has no support for interpolation of vertex normals. The closest effect you can get is [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading), which interpolates colors at vertices.

As stated in the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline):

> Hardware support for lighting only extended as far as the Blinn-Phong lighting model, computed per vertex and interpolated as a final light intensity.

Comment: This is not entirely true. If you assume fixed-function includes all of the extensions added to fixed-function fragment processing over the years, that would include `env_dot` and `env_crossbar`. With these, you can create a way to pass normals through to the shader and do dot-products with them to do some basic per-fragment lighting. However, you could consider this a primitive shading language, and pretty much any hardware that can do this can (and probably does) also implement ARB_shader_object/etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas my idea was to exploit multi texturing similarly like bump mapping was done by texture combiners that would provide per pixel lighting ... just a multi pass render similar to deferred rendering. However it would be sloow as using just `glReadPixels` instead of render to texture require transfer between CPU and GPU... And most likely some passes would be CPU based to achieve this. But still no shaders required.